# .htaccess $_GET specification

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.htaccess` code to maintain my URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^2014/?(?:([^/]+)/?|)(?:([^/]+)/?|)$ /data/2014/index.php?section=$1&subsection=$2 [L]
```

I need to modify it for cases, when i run `form` with `get` method. It makes output as (for ex.)

```
myweb.com/2014/about/?person=1&page=2
```

which I want URL to understand, I mean to get in the end hidden

```
myweb.com/data/2014/index.php?section=about&person=1&page=2
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

```
RewriteRule ^2014/...$ /data/...&subsection=$2 [L,QSA]
                                                  ^^^ here
```

That will append / combine the original query string to the rewritten url.